# Is there a way to find if key exists jsonpath-ng

Tags: python, jsonpath, jsonpath-ng

For example :

```py
client_json = {
    "data": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "creators": [
                    {
                        "name": "This is a person",
                        "nameType": "Personal",
                        "givenName": "the",
                        "familyName": "person"
                    },
                    {
                        "name": "This is an organization",
                        "nameType": "Organizational",
                        "givenName": "the",
                        "familyName": "organization"
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

In above json I want to check if keys exists for this json path `$.[0].attributes.creators[0].name,` I'm not worried about value.

Can I do that with `jsonpath-ng`? I have used `jsonpath` library by Stefan Goessner previously but that is old now.

I want something in python which is similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32397690/how-to-test-if-json-path-does-not-include-a-specific-element-or-if-the-element) but doesexist()

Comment: What path are you referring to?

Comment: Added the path.

Answer (score -2):

As far as I know, you wouldn't have to use any sort of libraries to do a lookup. Since Python handles JSON like dictionaries. This is what I would try:

```
for key in client_json.items():
    print key
```